# Ubuntu sftp disobeys ssh config files or bypasses ssh config settings

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp

I set up openssh on my server to listen to xx port and to use authorized_keys. From a Windows client, I am able to login to my server using my passphrase using putty. All Ok. This is what I wanted.

The problem now: With an Ubuntu desktop I use connect to server, I select the method = ssh, port = xx, host = ip, folder = correct folder, etc. Click connect and boom I am connected. Is this a bug?

When I use sftp using ssh to connect to a server, is it suppossed to obey the openssh config settings? Is it supposed to ask me for the passphrase instead of username/password?

If this the way it behaves then what other services are bypassing config files?

Could please give me a hint to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've specifically disabled password authentication, the server will accept either password or key authentication. Clients will typically attempt key authentication first and fallback to password authentication if it fails, but a client could attempt password authentication first.

You'll probably find that the Ubuntu desktop has cached your SSH key passphrase, either because your passphrase is the same as your login password, or because you've used it before during that session and the key has been cached.

Comment: mgorven, thanks for the input. I was guessing that. I can't reboot my system now. I read that it is a bug in ubuntu system but I am hoping that a reboot will do it. In ssh config file in my server I set it to no accept passwords at all. Only  key authentication. One other extrange thing that I noticed is that ubuntu claim that is a secure system since install. However after you install it you have access to all services like http, ssh, etc. It is hard for a new guy like me to realized that after install a service I have to go a change settings to restrict access. I am learning quickly